# Is $[0,1/2]$ m$^*$-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Definition: An outer measure m $^*$ on a set $X $ assigns to every subset of $X $ a nonnegative number such that.... (the three conditions)

Definition: Let m $^*$ be an outer measure on $X $. A set $E \subseteq X $ is called m $^*$-measurable if $m^*(T)=m^*(T \cap E) +m^* (T-E) $ for every $T \subseteq X $.

Is $[0,1/2]$ m$^*$-measurable?

No. Let $T=[0,1]$ and $E=[0,1/2]$. Then by definition $m^*(T \cap E)=1$ and $m^*(T-E)=1$. But $m^*(T)=1$ and $1 \neq 2$.

---

How are $m^*(T \cap E)=1$ and $m^*(T-E)=1$?

$T \cap E$ is $[0,1/2]$ isn't it?

And the other is $[1/2,1]$.

How are these $m^*$ stuff evaluated?

Comment: I think it depends on the choice of the measure,  maybe it's defined somewhere?

Comment: Would you agree with my complaints though?

Comment: Yes. For the Lebesgue measure all intervals are measurable, so whitout specifying the measure that statement is uncorrect

Comment: Never mind i think i get it now. I missed out something completely. Sorry for the useless post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $m^*-$measurable has no sense since $m^*$ is not a measure. Now, a set $E$ s.t. $m^*(E)=0$ is in fact measurable (it's easy to prove). Moreover, since the measure of an interval is it's length $$m^*(T\cap E)=m^*([0,1/2])=1/2$$
and $$m^*(T-E)=m^*([1/2,1])=1-1/2=1/2.$$

For the rest, it's unclear what you are asking !

Comment: i edited my post. Please have a look.